# Как правильно настроить «Порядковый номер в списке» в Google Play Console?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-console

Прошу помочь понять мне этот пункт в настройке рейтинга игроков. Например, что будет если я пропишу "200 из 1"?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: нажмите на вопросительный знак в круге

Comment: Я уже нажимал. Все равно мне не понятно.